# C# Json conversion error. (Pulled from api)

Tags: c#, json

I'm using an online Api Json but I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "{"Id":82800,"Name":"Pet Cage","Level":20,"Class":"Battle Pets","SubClass":"BattlePet","VendorBuy":0,"VendorSell":0,"MarketValue":0,"MinBuyout":0,"Quantity":0,"NumAuctions":0,"HistoricalPrice":0,"RegionMarketAvg":0,"RegionMinBuyoutAvg":0,"RegionQuantity":0,"RegionHistoricalPrice":38045754,"RegionSaleAvg":152352186,"RegionAvgDailySold":0,"RegionSaleRate":0,"URL":"https://www.tradeskillmaster.com/items/pet-cage-82800?realm=EU-ragnaros"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSM.Results]'. Path '', line 1, position 495.'

I want to get the Api Json (containing data) to show up in a list. I can get the data from the API but somewhere in my JSON conversion things go wrong.

I'm using the following code:

```
     HttpClient Connection = new HttpClient();

        Connection.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/82800?format=json&apiKey=***hidden***");
        Connection.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "TSM battle pet");

        HttpResponseMessage response = Connection.GetAsync("").Result;

        //var emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Results>>().Result;
        var emp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


        var New_Json = emp.Replace("\\\\", "");



        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New_Json);




        var parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(emp);
        foreach (var dataset in parsedObject.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataset.Name);
    }

       List<Results> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Results>>(json);   // <----- THIS ONE GIVE's THE ERROR
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error so I can correctly get it in the list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the exact value of *emp* please?  After the response returns

Comment: That JSON doesn't represent a list, that's why you see an error.

Comment: @Grantly It is : `"{\"Id\":82800,\"Name\":\"Pet Cage\",\"Level\":20,\"Class\":\"Battle Pets\",\"SubClass\":\"BattlePet\",\"VendorBuy\":0,\"VendorSell\":0,\"MarketValue\":0,\"MinBuyout\":0,\"Quantity\":0,\"NumAuctions\":0,\"HistoricalPrice\":0,\"RegionMarketAvg\":0,\"RegionMinBuyoutAvg\":0,\"RegionQuantity\":0,\"RegionHistoricalPrice\":38045754,\"RegionSaleAvg\":152352186,\"RegionAvgDailySold\":0,\"RegionSaleRate\":0,\"URL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.tradeskillmaster.com\\/items\\/pet-cage-82800?realm=EU-ragnaros\"}"`

Comment: Thanks...I wonder why you are Replacing this output and then SerializeObject it again?  Just DeserializeObject it instead...Try a single class as @DavidG said

Comment: @Grantly I've took use of some online tutorials, Even with the replacing output code removed it still won't allow me to deserialize it :/

Comment: Your JSON in your error message in between the quotes is fine.  I tested it - but its NOT a list.  The value of emp has escaped quotes which is wrong but could be due to other reasons...

Comment: I'll try again... You cannot deserialise something that is not a list into a `List<T>` in C#. So if the JSON doesn't have `[...]` and only has `{...}` then it's just an object, not an array of objects.

Comment: @DavidG I see, makes sence, how can I get them in a list though? So I can show them under eachother in a table

Comment: If you can't figure out how to put an item into a list, then perhaps you need to be running through some basic C# tutorials first?